# Jquery UI date picker and drop down

Tags: jquery

I'm using two jquery ui date picker and a drop down.Each of them are functions so, totally,i've three function's.

My question here is how do i take those three values and pass it to a ajax function?

Is there any alternative for this?

**Sample**

```
          $ajax{
              url
               post 
              data

               }
```

Answer (score 1):

The values for each field should be available using the ID of the field. I'm assuming you have some sort of onclick event that fires your ajax? when this occurs, then retrieve the values from each field, i.e.: $('#field1').val();

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your datepickers and dropdown in a `<form>` tag you can then use jquery `.serialize`.

It would look something like this

```
$.get(myUrl, $('#myForm').serialize(), function () {
    alert('I submitted this data'+ $('#myForm').serialize()');
});
```

`get` is a shortcut for `ajax` which populates the method and the transfer encoding types for you.